# SMS Gateways - what language are they written in?

Tags: sms-gateway

I want to have a way for mobile devices to interact with my web application (not browser, but text message).  I know that an SMS gateway is probably the right choice.

I want to have something like texting 'some command' to an email address on my server and then having my server carry out that command. Is this what an SMS gateway is used for? Why are the only gateways available provided by companies that want to charge you for them? Are they that hard to make? What process is involved in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't that they are hard to make, it is that the carriers charge them for accessing the network to send/receive SMS messages.

When you send an SMS via a gateway you are charged by the gateway and they are charged by the carrier.

They are language agnostic, I know some written in Perl, others in Java and C.

Comment: so I can't use mynumber@carrierdomain to send text messages legally?

Comment: Sure - some SMS gateways support email to SMS, in exactly that format, but they'll bill you for each SMS sent.